# Spring batch - Disappearing threads While using Partioner

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch to process voluminous data daily. So we are ready to go with Spring batch Partioning concept.

Below is my configuration :`

```
    <job id="test" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="masterStep">
      <partition step="step2" partitioner="multiPartioner">
        <handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
      </partition>
    </step>
  </job>

  <bean id="multiPartioner"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner"
    scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters[fileDirectory]}/*" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  </bean>

    <step id="step2" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
      <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <chunk reader="multiResourceItemReader" writer="testWriter"
          commit-interval="20000">
        </chunk>
      </tasklet>
    </step>
```

When I try to specify the corePoolSize as 4 , it is working fine without any issues. But if I increase the count of corePoolSize to 10 , it is executing but after some time say 20 mins nothing was executed . No Logs or no error . No status about what is happening . It was idle no execution further.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you show your reader and writer too?

Comment: If an exception is raised in a thread and the exception is not handled the thread dies silently. Validate via registering a UncaughtExceptionHandler in your application root if this is happening: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)

Comment: @Michael/@Andreas : Found that issue seems to be with connection pooling in my data source. Where I initialized my thread count more than the default pooling size , so all thread comes to waiting state to get the connection from exhausted pool. Thnx for your reply.